# if statement executing after condition failed (C- Multithreading)

Tags: c, multithreading, logging, udp, pthreads

I encountered this problem in my project, and I don't know what I have to do next (It's happening only when load test and it is a multi-threaded programming). **Problem related to if which is inside else-if...**

```
#define FAILURE -1
#define SUCCESS 1
#define ERROR_GETTING -203

#define NON_MMS_DEST_CLIENT 2
#define OTHER_NETWORK_DEST_CLIENT 6

int get_event_type(char *eventtype, char *domainname, char *dest, int sendertype)
{
     int iret=0;
     int spin_retStatus=0;

     ret = get_client_interface_type (tbuff) ;
     log_msg (g_log_fp, LOG_DEBUG, "ret [%d] from get_client_interface_type",ret);

     if(ret == NON_MMS_DEST_CLIENT)
     {
        /* which is not executing in current scenario */
     }

     else if(ret == OTHER_NETWORK_DEST_CLIENT)
     {
        /* I'm getting return value as 6 which is OTHER_NETWORK_DEST_CLIENT */

        log_msg(g_log_fp,LOG_DEBUG,"Establishing connection");
        spin_retStatus=contact_event_type_over_udp(tbuff,&domain,NULL,0);

        /* return values: SUCCESS & FAILURE */

        if(FAILURE == spin_retStatus)
             iret=ERROR_GETTING;

        log_msg(g_log_fp,LOG_DEBUG,"Crash Debug:: spin_retStatus: %d,iret= %d",spin_retStatus,iret);
    }
...
/*
I'm performing some actions based on above return values
*/
}

int contact_event_type_over_udp (char *cl_addr, char** domain_name, LOC_INFO *location_info, int ati_req_type)
{
      int call_ret =0;
      /* some other variables */

      if(cl_addr == NULL)
      {
           log_msg (g_log_fp, LOG_WARNING, "ERROR: Invalid MSISDN.") ;
           call_ret = FAILURE ;
           goto end_req_buff;
      }
      else
      {
            /* some code but at the end it will return SUCCESS there is no FAILURE case in else loop*/
            call_ret = SUCCESS;
            goto end_req_buff;
      }

      end_req_buff:
          /* freeing all the pointer buffers */
          return call_ret;
}
```

Here is my output (**Note: I'm getting this output only in some times, remaining time I'm getting output as we expected based on code**)

```
14-07-2015 07:31:41 [176028528] Establishing connection
14-07-2015 07:31:41 [176028528] Crash Debug:: call_ret [1] mms.mtn.com.gh
14-07-2015 07:31:41 [176028528] Crash Debug:: spin_retStatus: 1, iret=-203
```

This is copied from log file and here **2nd statement is the return value of "contact_event_type_over_udp" function and I'm getting return value as 1 (which is SUCCESS by #define) but I'm getting iret value -203.**

I'm just analysing possible situations but I didn't get in which case this iret getting ERROR_GETTING value (**the number in [] is thread process to identify same thread or different thread** and here I'm giving all outputs based on same thread)

Here is the other case which we are getting values based on condition:

```
14-07-2015 07:37:17 [176028528] Establishing connection
14-07-2015 07:37:17 [176028528] Crash Debug:: call_ret [1] mms.mtn.com.gh
14-07-2015 07:37:17 [176028528] Crash Debug:: spin_retStatus: 1, iret=0


14-07-2015 07:38:41 [176028528] Crash Debug:: call_ret [-1]
14-07-2015 07:38:41 [176028528] Crash Debug:: spin_retStatus: -1, iret=-203
```

Somebody please help me to solve this issue, if you need more code I'll provide but this 'iret' variable I never used another places (whatever I give the code that portion only contains iret variable)

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: Code formatted. Need anything

Comment: This isn't clear.  Why do you believe that this code path shouldn't be taken?  Please construct a [minimal test-case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I added some more code which is specifically related to the problem case.

Comment: I am not seeing any visible issue here. Why don't you try putting logs for iret more frequently in your code e.g. before and after calling contact_event_type_over_udp() function. Or try changing iret to "unsigned int"; see if this make some changes. I don't have an explicit answer here, just trying to explore few options?

Comment: I tried that then only I concluded that some times this iret getting -203 even though if block condition fail. I would like to know is there any chance it may happen in multi threading or not ?

Comment: From your code, it is not possible for iret to have value other than FAILURE/SUCCESS/0/ERROR_GETTING until you are having some other code where "iret" is modified. How do you say that even after using "unsigned int iret" shows you negative value?? It is not possible.

Comment: Are you sure that `log_msg` is thread-safe? Keep in mind you are logging to a shared resource. Acces to it should be serialised.

Comment: Also here `ret = get_client_interface_type ( ...` it is unclear where and how `ret` is defined.